# Import-PfxCertificate not insert my CA in root store

Tags: powershell, certificate, ssl-certificate, salt-stack, ca

I don't know if my question is a bit silly or not (I'm not a Windows pro) but after several searches to import CAs that are contained in a p12 file with Import-PfxCertificate, I can't put in the store I want, namely LocalMachine\Root.
Indeed, the CAs put themselves in "Intermediate Certification Authorities".

Here are the two commands I use :

```
$secure_password = ConvertTo-SecureString $args[0] -AsPlainText -Force
Import-PfxCertificate -Password $secure_password -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\Root -FilePath c:/Users/user1/Documents/export.p12
```

This script is used in SaltStack execution on a Windows minion.
Even if I change and write Cert:\LocalMachine\My instead of Root, it doesn't work.

Can somebody help me ?

Comment: "Indeed, the CAs put themselves in "Intermediate Certification Authorities"." - might that be because they _are_ intermediate CA certificates? Does the p12 contain an actual (self-signed) root certificate that you don't trust already?

Comment: Mmh yes those are self-signed certificates but I don't think I have trust it already